# Rails 5 compatibility between Paranoia and CanCanCan, compromised?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan, ruby-paranoia

I'm having the exact same issue as described on this thread:

[Rails 5 only_deleted with cancancan #356](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/issues/356)

I can access a deleted record, like this:

```
    @area = Area.only_deleted.find(params[:id])
```

but if I add `load_and_authorize_resource` to my controller, it'll attempt to run the query like this:

```
    @area = Area.find(params[:id])
```

which will result in error since it won't find a record with that id on a collection where deleted_at isn't null (not deleted records, the purpose of the Paranoia gem).

If I disable `load_and_authorize_resource` for the controller or for that very action, it solves the error but it's not a solution since that means losing authorization control.

Is there a fix for this, or is there an authorization gem which plays nice with Paranoia on Rails 5 which I could switch over to?

Thank you.

Comment: try replace the `set_area` method with  `def set_area @area= Area.with_deleted.find(params[:id])
    end`

Comment: leads to the same result as only_deleted, cancancan isn't playing nice with  paranoia's scopes for some reason, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: The strange thing that I have the same two gems And they play very nicely, Only I have rails 4.2

Comment: Which versions are you using? Here paranoia is 2.2.0.pre, cancancan 1.15.0 and Rails 5.0.0.1

Comment: Sorry but it turned out that I use acts_as_paranoid (0.5.0) not paranoia, cancancan (1.15.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to [documentation on load_and_authorize_resource](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/CanCan%2FControllerAdditions%2FClassMethods%3Aload_resource), the method will attempt to load an instance variable in case one hasn't been set yet, and won't do so if there's a set instance variable, which is precisely why the application was breaking:

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  before_action :set_area, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...     

  def set_area
    if session[:show_obsolete_records] == true
      @area = Area.only_deleted.find(params[:id])
    else
      @area = Area.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

`load_and_authorize_resource` runs first on the list, and since there were no instance variables set before its call, it does `@area = Area.find(params[:id])` on its own account, which obviously leads to error, since **Paranoia** overwrittes finder methods to include a condition to check whether the `deleted_at` is `NULL`.

For example, when using the regular (without **Paranoia**) `Area.find(17)`, you get a query like this on your console:

```
Area Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "areas".* FROM "areas" WHERE "areas"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

When using **Paranoia**, you'd get this query:

```
Area Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "areas".* FROM "areas" WHERE ("areas"."deleted_at" IS NULL) AND "areas"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

This way, records that have been deleted won't be found on common queries since they'll have the `deleted_at` timestamp set (`deleted_at` is now `NOT NULL`).

To access deleted records, you **must** use either `with_deleted` or `only_deleted`, like

`@area = Area.only_deleted.find(params[:id])`

or else it won't find the deleted record, hence why I was getting the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Area with 'id'=16 [WHERE "areas"."deleted_at" IS NULL]:
```

The method `load_and_authorize_resource` loaded `@area = Area.find(params[:id])` and skipped `set_area`, so you could delete the method and it would still set the area even if the code is not there.

The solution is to simply move the `load_and_authorize_resource` method below the callbacks list:

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_area, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  load_and_authorize_resource

  ...     

  def set_area
    if session[:show_obsolete_records] == true
      @area = Area.only_deleted.find(params[:id])
    else
      @area = Area.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

You can leave the method call `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top at the stack, but change it to `authorize_resource` so it doesn't attempt to call `@area = Area.find(params[:id])`, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075500/how-to-understand-load-resource-and-authorize-resource-methods-of-cancancan-gem).

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController

  authorize_resource

  before_action :set_area, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...     

  def set_area
    if session[:show_obsolete_records] == true
      @area = Area.only_deleted.find(params[:id])
    else
      @area = Area.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```